# boost::asio acceptor pointer crash issue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I create two classes =>   Superclass:TcpServer  Subclass:AccountServer
when I was assigning the shared pointer of acceptor in AccountServer, it crashed. This situation came out only when the acceptor is the data member of the TcpServer, if I put the acceptor into the AccountServer, it's fine. There are some codes and information below, hope someone can tell me why, it would be grateful.

```
class TcpServer
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> ServicePtr;
    **typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> AcceptorPtr;**
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint> EndpointPtr;
    TcpServer();
    ~TcpServer();
    void init();
protected:
    EndpointPtr m_pEndpoint;
    ServicePtr m_pService;
    **AcceptorPtr m_pAcceptor;**
};

class AccountServer : public TcpServer
{
public:
    **typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> AcceptorPtr;**
    AccountServer();
    ~AccountServer();
    void init();
private:   
    Json::Value m_AccountConf;
    **//AcceptorPtr m_pAcceptor;**   //delete this line so that the m_pAcceptor in the
                                     //super class will be used in the runtime 
};

void my::AccountServer::init()
{
    int port = 10000;
    m_pService = ServicePtr(new boost::asio::io_service());
    m_pEndpoint = EndpointPtr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port));
    **m_pAcceptor = AcceptorPtr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(*m_pService, *m_pEndpoint));     // here is where it crashed**
    ...other codes
}
```

[image]
[image]

I think the acceptor destructed as soon as it has been assigned, but why, and why did it crash. I'm totally confused now. If any of you know anything about this problem, you are more than welcome to tell me, that would be very appreciative. :)

Comment: This calls for a **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)** / **[mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Note that putting `m_pAcceptor` in both the `TcpServer` and `the `AccountServer` class makes very little sense (and the derived member will hide the the base class member, but the server will see the unassigned one).

Comment: My problem is that when I was deleting the m_pAcceptor in the AccountServer class and using the one in the TcpServer, it crashed. I just wanna know why.   But you are right about the "putting in both class" thing, thanks for your help :)